# Existence of planar graph whose faces correspond to the faces of a convex polyhedron

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, polyhedra, planar-graphs, stereographic-projections

Wikipedia states that Steinitz's theorem says:

> "a given graph $G$ is the graph of a convex three-dimensional
>   polyhedron, if and only if $G$ is planar and $3$-vertex-connected"

So, given a convex polyhedron, there exists a planar graph whose vertices correspond to the vertices of the polyhedron and similar for the edges. However, if one wishes to deduce Euler's formula for polyhedrons from Euler's formula for planar graphs, it is also necessary for the faces of the planar graph (including the unbounded face) to correspond to the faces of the polyhedron.

How can we show that, given a convex polyhedron, a planar graph exists such that, not only the vertices and edges of the graph correspond to those of the polyhedron, but that the faces correspond as well?

I have read in some sources that stereographic projection does the trick, or that a light source can be shined from above the polyhedron, but these arguments are rather intuitive. I would appreciate seeing a proof that is as rigorous as possible or being pointed to one.

Comment: Once a polyhedron has been projected onto the surface of a bounding sphere, via $(x,y,z)\to(x/r,y/r,z/r)$ with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ (where the origin was somewhere inside the polyhedron), stereographic projection relative to a pole within (a spherical region corresponding to) a face *is* rigorous. It's a continuous transformation of the (punctured) sphere to the plane, so it preserves the vertex-edge-face structure from the spherical polyhedron, with the "pole face" of the spherical polyhedron corresponding to the "outer/unbounded face" of the planar graph. How much more rigor do you need?

Comment: Well, there are details, which are commonly left out. Why does every polyhedron have a bounding sphere? Why does there exist a point in the interior of a projected space? Sure, one can likely fill in the details for oneself, but it makes the proof feel sloppy at times...

Comment: @Blue, your response is already better than what I have seen elsewhere as other sources gloss over the idea of first projecting onto to surface of a bounding sphere before applying stereographic projection. However, copying PrudiiArca, it would be good to know why projecting onto the bounding sphere preserves the vertex-edge-face structure. Feel free to respond with an answer, including your previous ideas, instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Stereographic projection indeed is the trick. Just use the center of projection very Little above one of its faces. Then the whole polyhedron gets projected right into the projection of this very face. This projection then is nothing but the **Schlegel diagram** of the polyhedron wrt. the chosen face.

Btw. that a polyhedron always provides a graph via its edge skeleton is the easy part. The other way round, i.e. classifying which graphs can be understood in this way as a projection of some polyhedron, that is what the Steinitz theorem is aiming for.

--- rk